# Automapper merging objects issue

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

After getting automapper to work ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602430/automapper-complex-types-mapping-exception)), I'm struggling with another problem (took it to another question, so the first one wouldn't be too complicated)...

I have next classes:

```
public class Model1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
}    
public class Model2
{
    public bool Married { get; set; }    
    public int Children { get; set; }
    public bool HasPet { get; set; }
}

public class Entity1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
}    
public class Entity2
{
    public bool Married { get; set; }    
    public int Children { get; set; }
    public bool HasPet { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
}
```

*These objects are schematically similar to my original objects, except to the name and the complexity.*

And AutoMapper configuration class (called from Global.asax):

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; set; }

    public static void Configure()
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile<Out>();
            cfg.CreateMap<SuperModel, SuperEntity>();
        });
        MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}

public class Out: Profile
{
   protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Model1, Entity1>();
        CreateMap<Model2, Entity2>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NickName, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<Model1, Entity2>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Married, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HasPet, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<SuperModel, SuperEntity>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Model1))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Model2));
    }
}
```

When I need the object to be converted, I do next (at this point I have `_superModel` initialized and filled with data):

```
SuperEntity _superEntity = new SuperEntity();
AutoMapperConfig.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper().Map<SuperModel, SuperEntity>(_superModel, _superEntity);
```

So, I map `Model1` to `Entity1` (witch is fine), and also `Model2` to `Entity2` (witch is also fine, except the Id property, which is ignored).

Main objects `SuperModel` and `SuperEntity` are mapped as well, and seems to work fine.

The problem happens, when I map `Model1` to `Entity2`, to get the `NickName` (thought the rest of the properties are ignored). Some how It is always `null`!

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you doing the maps?

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca You're right, I forgot to mention it. Please see the question again - just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you want to map a destination property (`Entity2`) from multiples source property values (`Children`, `Married` and `HasPet` from `Model2` and `Nickname` from `Model1`).

You can solve your situation using an [Custom Resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) or with [AfterMap](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions) method.

**Using Custom Resolvers**:

You have to create a class inhering from `ValueResolver` to define how you will map `Entity2` from an `SuperModel`:

```
public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<SuperModel, Entity2>
{
    protected override Entity2 ResolveCore(SuperModel source)
    {
        return new Entity2
        {
            Children = source.Model2.Children,
            HasPet = source.Model2.HasPet,
            Married = source.Model2.Married,
            NickName = source.Model1.NickName
        };
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
CreateMap<SuperModel, SuperEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Model1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity2, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

**Using AfterMap**:

You can execute actions after the mapping, so pass the value from `Model1.Nickname` to `Entity2.Nickname` after the map:

```
CreateMap<SuperModel, SuperEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Model1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Model2))
            .AfterMap((m, e) => e.Entity2.NickName = m.Model1.NickName);
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! I'll try it first thing on the morning (already off my work). Hope this works :) so I could finally finish the module and vote the answer :)