# Automapper RecognizePostfix method doesn't works with an array oh postfixes

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Finally got automapper to work: [previous question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602430/automapper-complex-types-mapping-exception), [previous question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701769/automapper-merging-objects-issue).

For now I have something like this:

```
public class Steps
{
    public PersonalModel Personal1 { get; set; }
    public CompanyModel Company2 { get; set; }
    public SposeModel Spose3 { get; set; }
}    
public class PersonalModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}    
public class CompanyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
public class SposeModel
{
    public string Age { get; set; }    
}
```

And:

```
public class Content
{
    public string Dummy1 { get; set; }
    public string Dummy2 { get; set; }
    public string Dummy3 { get; set; }
    public string Dummy4 { get; set; }
    public string Dummy5 { get; set; }

    public Personal Personal { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Spose Spose { get; set; }
}    
public class Personal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}    
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
public class Spose
{
    public string Age { get; set; }    
}
```

*These objects are schematically similar to my original objects, except to the name and the complexity.*

And mapping looks like this:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; set; }

    public static void Configure()
    {
        MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile<Out>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Steps, Content>();
        });
        MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}

public class Out: Profile
{
   protected override void Configure()
   {
      CreateMap<PersonalModel, Personal>();
      CreateMap<CompanyModel, Company>();
      CreateMap<SposeModel, Spose>();

      CreateMap<Steps, Content>();
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Personal, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Personal1))
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Company, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company2))
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Spose, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Spose3))
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy1, opt => opt.Ignore())
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy2, opt => opt.Ignore())
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy3, opt => opt.Ignore())
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy4, opt => opt.Ignore())
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy5, opt => opt.Ignore());
   }
}
```

I want to optimize the mapping (*took it to another question not to make another to be too complicated*), as at the [AutoMapper Configuration Documentation at GitHub](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration), I saw the `RecognizePostfix` method. But when I put next line within the configuration section:

```
cfg.RecognizePostfix(new string[3] {"1", "2", "3"});
```

And remove next from the profile:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Personal, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Personal1))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Company, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company2))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Spose, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Spose3))
```

I get an exception:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Unmapped members were
>   found. Review the types and members below. Add a custom mapping
>   expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the
>   source/destination type

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't know if this should be considered a bug or is how it's supposed to work, but apparently *pre/postfixes* only works for the profile where it was defined.

In your case, you can quickly fix your problem moving the `RecognizePostfixes` call to the profile:

```
public static void Configure()
{
    MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.AddProfile<Out>();
    });
    MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
...
```

And the profile:

```
public class Out : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        RecognizePostfixes("1", "2", "3");

        CreateMap<PersonalModel, Personal>();
        CreateMap<CompanyModel, Company>();
        CreateMap<SposeModel, Spose>();

        CreateMap<Steps, Content>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy1, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy2, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy3, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy4, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Dummy5, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```